# Deploy GoCD pipeline to AWS Ec2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, go-cd

I intend to deploy a python script script from GoCD running locally to an AWS ec2 instance, or any web server. 
After researching for a week I could not find any recommendations.

What commands would enable GOCD to install a dependency on a remote server and deploy basic code to the server to run?

Assuming that the git is already integrated to pull the repo into the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently three methods my team have used to achieve this;

1. Add the SSH key and usernames into the SSH config of the go user. That way you can execute commands such as `scp source-script server1:/dir`.
2. Install a GoCD agent onto the server you want to deploy files to. That way you can move the files around the server without SSH.
3. Use a third party application such as Rundeck to deploy out. You'd use GoCD to upload the file into Rundeck as an option and execute the job onto a fleet of servers.